# PHP/MySQL - COUNT 2 different totals within 1 Table for each User

Tags: php, mysql, count

I can't get my head around this one!! So I'm seeking help....

For each user I'm trying to sum the types of posts assigned to them.

User Table: crm_users
Columns: users_id, users_first, users_last

Posts Table: crm_entities
Columns: crm_id, users_id, settype, post

I would like to COUNT() the total posts for a user where settype=draft as well as settype=published, for example:

```
Name------------Published---------Drafts
John Smith---------15---------------3
Nancy Grace--------11-------------  5
Jay Martin----------7--------------14
```

I am sure I am making this more difficult than it probably is... or at least I think !

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because MySQL uses 1 as representation for `true` and 0 for `false`, you could use:

```sql
SELECT
    u.users_first,
    u.users_last,
    SUM(p.settype='published') as Published,
    SUM(p.settype='draft') as Drafts
FROM
    crem_users u
LEFT JOIN
    crm_entities p
ON
    u.users_id = p.users_id
GROUP BY
    u.users_id
ORDER BY Published DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select u.users_first, (select count(*) as qty from crm_entities e where e.settype='draft' and e.users_id = u.users_id) drafts, (select count(*) as qty from crm_entities e where e.settype='published' and e.users_id = u.users_id) published from crm_users u
```